# Applications of Artin's theorem on induced representations

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $R(G)$ be the (complex) representation ring of $G$.  As stated in Serre's book on representation theory, Artin's theorem says the following:

**Theorem**: Let $X$ be a family of subgroups of $G$.  Let $\operatorname{Ind}\colon \bigoplus_{H \in X} R(H) \rightarrow R(G)$ be the homomorphism given by induction.  Then the following properties are equivalent:

1. $G$ is the union of the conjugates of the subgroups belonging to $X$; and
2. The cokernel of $\operatorname{Ind}\colon \bigoplus_{H \in X} R(H) \rightarrow R(G)$ is finite.

Since Serre devotes a whole chapter to this theorem, I assume it is quite important.  However, he doesn't really give any applications of it.  Can anyone explain why it is such an important result, and in particular how it is used?

Comment: See this answer from math SE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4854649/artins-theorem-for-the-linear-representation-of-finite-groups

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as @Deif [points out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464479/applications-of-artins-theorem-on-induced-representations#comment1206350_464479), it is a duplicate of [Artin's theorem for the linear representation of finite groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4854649/artins-theorem-for-the-linear-representation-of-finite-groups). \\ @‍Deif, I assume you meant to link to @‍KCd's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4854696) rather than the question?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, you're right.

Comment: @Deif: So should I take from that answer that Artin's Theorem is not really important for representation theory per se, but only to applications of representation theory to arithmetic (and then only for historical value since it's been superceded by Brauer's theorem)?